# Coroutine WaitForSeconds affected by timeScale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am working on a simple animation for my UI elements.

I have an animator component which has 2 different animations - ZoomIn and ZoomOut.

These animations are displayed whenever an UI element (e.g. Button) needs to be displayed on the screen.

I normally prefer deactivating the gameobject when not displaying.

I have written the following method for the animations:

```
private IEnumerator ToggleObjectWithAnimation (GameObject gameObj) {
        Animator gameObjectAnimator = gameObj.GetComponent ();   // Animator is set to unscaled time
        if (gameObj.activeSelf == false) {
            gameObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 1.0f);
            gameObj.SetActive (true);
            gameObjectAnimator.SetTrigger ("ZoomIn");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
        } else if(gameObj.activeSelf == true) {
            gameObjectAnimator.SetTrigger ("ZoomOut");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
            gameObj.SetActive (false);   // code not execute when timescale = 0
        }
        yield return null;
}
```

The code works fine when for most of the screens, but shows problem when I pause the game using timescale = 0.

When timescale is 0, the line gameObj.SetActive (false) does not work.

Comment: how about you put Debug.Log("test"); before gameObj.SetActive (false);  and see if if the Log shows up.

Comment: It's a good example of why you never change the timeScale in Unity.  Pausing a game is very difficult and involves a lot of code.  You have to write pause routines for every element in the game.  A few years ago someone on the internet mentioned that you can "change the timeScale" to pause a game in Unity, which is just ridiculous. That comment has been repeated all over the internet and now beginners and hobbyists have their time wasted with it.

Comment: I have already tried adding Debug.Logs.

Comment: The code is breaking in the else block after the line - yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f); Though the Log after the yield statement is not displayed but I am sure that the yield block is executed as I am able to see the animation. But the line - gameObj.SetActive (false) is never executed.

Comment: @Joe Blow - Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't knew that changing the timescale is a bad practice. Although I have tried pausing my game without using timescale, but I have a major challenge in doing so. My game is paused when my character hits an unexpected object. Now, my character can be in the process of executing a certain animation when it collides with the other object. So while pausing my game I want my character to be in the interim state of animation, rather completing it. This was easy to achieve using timescale = 0.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's probably a bit late but:

The problem is not the `SetActive` but that [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) is affected by the [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)!

> The actual time suspended is equal to the given time **multiplied by [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)**. See [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) if you wish to wait using **unscaled** time.

So if you have `Time.timescale=0` the `WaitForSeconds` will never finish!

---

You shoul rather use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html)

```
private IEnumerator ToggleObjectWithAnimation (GameObject gameObj) 
{
    Animator gameObjectAnimator = gameObj.GetComponent ();   // Animator is set to unscaled time

    if (gameObj.activeSelf == false) 
    {
        gameObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 1.0f);
        gameObj.SetActive (true);
        gameObjectAnimator.SetTrigger ("ZoomIn");
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
    } 
    else if(gameObj.activeSelf == true) 
    {
        gameObjectAnimator.SetTrigger ("ZoomOut");
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
        gameObj.SetActive (false);   // code not execute when timescale = 0
    }
    yieldr eturn null;
}
```